# Are questions about legal issues on topic?

Tags: discussion

By legal issues I'm referring specifically to
- legal issues for exit operators
- legal issues for relay operators
- legal issues for bridge operators

I'm thinking topics such as DMCA notices, logging requirements, safe-harbour provisions for ISPs etc.

Answer (score 9):

To play devlis advocate (and give people an opposite point of view to vote on):

I think legal questions should be okay so long as we make a few things clear:

- We're not lawyers and (even if we are) can't give proper legal advice
- Questions that only require "yes/no" answers are generally considered poor form
- Questions should be about specific things; overly broad questions are a bad idea (in general, but I feel like this will happen a lot more with legal questions)

If anyone has any ideas for `good/bad' legal questions, please comment with some examples.

Comment: If I'm reading you right, this could allow questions such as "I want to host an exit node in Russia. What laws should I be careful of violating?" Hmm...

Comment: If we were allow legal questions, I think that one would be okay. It's a fine line, and I'm having a hard time deciding where I think it should be drawn.

Answer (score 2):

I think the two previous answers (TLDR: "yes" and "no") sort of establish a necessary middle-ground for this topic.  Perhaps we should not issue a blanket ban (or allow) on legal questions but instead be sure to closely moderate and consider on a case-by-case basis with the necessary caveats included in the FAQ.

Addionally, "legal-issue" tag might need to be applied to these questions (by someone in the community if not already done by the asker) and that tag should have a well-crafted tag-wiki with the same information.

On that note, does Stack have any kind of functionality that could automatically add some link or note to a page containing a question with this tag?

Comment: *does Stack have any kind of functionality that could automatically add some link or note to a page containing a question with this tag?* No. Stuff like adding notices is never automated. Its part of a  moderators' work.

Answer (score -2):

I'm thinking that such legal issues are off-topic, as they will be too broad, or localised (depending on whether there was a country in question specified).

Comment: Presonally, I'm with you. For every legal question I can think of that would be okay, I can think of 3 more that I think wouldn't be good.

Comment: Too localized doesn't automatically apply if a question happens to be relevant to a single country. Some countries make up over 10% of the world population for example.